# Jade to HTML > index.html inside directory named after jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug

I've got a simple gulp task that compiles a `.jade` file to an `.html` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade');

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/templates/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade()) // pip to jade plugin
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public')); // tell gulp our output folder
});
```

### Issue

`/src/templates/page.jade` is compiled to HTML at the destination `/public/page.html`

How would I get it so it would compile `/src/templates/page.jade` to `/public/page/index.html`.

I.e. every new jade file in `templates` gets compiled to a an html file called `index.html` inside a directory with the same name as the source jade file?

#### Examples

`/src/templates/about.jade` >> `/public/about/index.html`

`/src/templates/contact.jade` >> `/public/contact/index.html`

`/src/templates/features.jade` >> `/public/features/index.html`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include sub-directories you can go with:

```
    .pipe(rename(function(path){             
         if(path.basename != 'index')
         {
            var crumbs = path.dirname.split('/')
            crumbs.push(path.basename)

            path.basename = 'index'
            path.extname = '.html'

            path.dirname = crumbs.join('/')
        }

        return path
    }))
```

I've been using this with success on a front-matter solution.  Don't forget to include /** before /*.filetype in the gulp.src

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is [gulp-rename](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename) plugin. Play around the following code, maybe it will solve your problem.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade')
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/templates/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(rename(function(path) {
        var filename = path.basename;
        path.basename = 'index';
        path.extname = '.html';
        path.dirname = filename;
        return path;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a combination of some gulp trickery and proper usage of Jade itself.

the following works for me, and results with index.html including all other files:

1) Project Structure:

```
- src
-- templates
--- footer.jade
--- layout.jade
-- index.jade
```

2) gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
jade = require('gulp-jade');
gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src(['!src/templates/**/*.jade', 'src/index.jade'])
    .pipe(jade()) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public')); 
});
```

Notice i've changed the src input. first, the source files are passed to gulp as an array. second, i've added an '!' (exclamation mark) before the files you want gulp to ignore.

3) Jade

you can (and should) use include/extend to tell jade how to assemble your page eventually. 
for example, this is what my files include:

**src/templates/footer.jade**

```
h1
   some text
```

**src/templates/layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    block title
      title Default title
  body
    block content
```

**src/index.jade**

```
extends ./templates/layout.jade

block title
  title Article Title

block content
  h1 My Article

  include ./templates/footer.jade
```

Hope this helps. I'm just learning this too :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use gulp-rename:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade')
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/views/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename(function(path){
        if (path.basename=='index'){
          return;
        }
        path.dirname=path.basename.split('-').join('/');
        path.basename="index";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
    callback();
});
```