# Compile Jade to HTML while keeping folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug, gulp-rename

I'm using Gulp, Gulp Jade, and Gulp Rename to create a static site with canonical URLs.

Currently this script:

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/views/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename(function(path){
        if (path.basename=='index'){
          return;
        }
        path.dirname=path.basename.split('-').join('/');
        path.basename="index";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
    callback();
});
```

allows me to compile the following files:

`/src/views/index.jade` >> `/public/index.html` (home page)

`/src/views/about.jade` >> `/public/about/index.html` (about page)

This means that I can have canonical URLs at http://example.com/ (for index.jade) and http://example.com/about/ (for about.jade).

However, I want to be able to have more than 1 level in the URL structure.  For example, if I wanted a page about Dave at the URL `http://example.com/about/dave/` I would do this:

#### I want to achieve this:

`/src/views/about/dave.jade` >> `/public/about/dave/index.html`

#### But, the result is:

`/src/views/about/dave.jade` >> `/public/dave/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Here's similar question: [Jade to HTML > index.html inside directory named after jade file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732924/jade-to-html-index-html-inside-directory-named-after-jade-file/33733610) where you'll find a nice code sample for gulp-rename which does work.

Answer (score 0):

Jade has been renamed to "Pug" and now preservers the directory structure by default when given a directory as the input to compile.

Here's a simple example:

**Pug Source:**

```
source/
    templates/
      |-- index.pug
      |-- about.pug
    partials/
      |-- navigation.pug
```

**Command to Compile:**

```
pug source --out ./build
```

**Outputs as:**

```
build/
    templates/
      |-- index.html
      |-- about.html
    partials/
      |-- navigation.html
```